# Detect Push Notifications Android

Tags: android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver

I am creating a chat application(kind of watsapp) in Android.

Here one of the core and important point is that , i need to use my own server instead of GCM.

So that , how can i code my manifest file so that whenever there is new message from server it will automatically detect in my broadcast receivers.?

Comment: You're question denotes a huge lack of search...

Comment: regret for that , but i am not able to find the right path

Comment: Why would you avoid GCM? How would you send push notifications? How yould you receive them in your Android application? You must have some links about it...

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to have is a good reason to not use GCM. If you are sure you want your own service, you will have to write a lot of code, on client side **and** on server side. Here is the general idea :

1. Register a broadcast receiver to know when the device is connected or not to network.
2. Create a service that will be launch and stop by the broadcast receiver accoding to the device network status.
3. Choose a pattern for "push". You can use classic HTTP request with long-polling, or sockets to do real push. This [link](http://fr.slideshare.net/NenadPecanac/reverse-ajax-in-2014) present the concept (for web use).
4. Implement this pattern so you service will comunicate with your server.
5. Make your service broadcast intent, so the rest of your app can receive push.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others on this. You should be using the GCM, even if it means adding your own custom server side code.

Here is what my broadcast receiver looked like with an test app for GCM push notifications.

```
public class GCMBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String TAG = "GCMBroadcastReceiver_";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        Log.v(TAG, "OnReceive was called.");
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GCMNotificationIntentService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

In the intent service (GCMNotificationIntentService), you create the actual notification.

Here is the example I've been working off:

https://github.com/kweaver00/android-learning/tree/master/Push

https://github.com/kweaver00/android-learning/blob/master/Push/GCMExample/app/src/main/java/com/expeditionlabs/gcmexample/lib/gcm/GCMBroadcastReceiver.java